# how can I save output as a float in python

Tags: python

How can I save output as a float datatype.

```
def div_by_one(input):
    var = 1/input
    print var
    return var
```

This prints var as 0 instead of 0.125 for input=8.

Comment: use can give the input either as `8.0` i.e as a float, or you can do `1.0/input`

Answer (score 3):

Use `1.0` to let Python infer that you want a float.

```
def div_by_one(input):
    var = 1.0/input
    print var
    return var
```

Answer (score 0):

just convert input number to float just like below

```
def div_by_one(num):
    var = 1.0 / float(num)
    print var
    return var
```

Answer (score 0):

def div_by_one(input):
    var = 1.0/float(input)
    print format(var, '.2f')
    return format(var, '.2f')

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2.7 then you can do this

```
def div_by_one(input):
    var = 1//input
    return var

ans = div_by_one(8)
print(ans)                    #Prints 0.125
```